# Transformation of sum equation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $X_t$ the sum of t random variables. I want to show:
$$\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{m=k}^{s+c-1}\frac{c+s-m}{c+s-k} P(X_{c+s-k}=m-k) \overset{!}{=}\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{t=0}^{s+c-k}\left(1-\frac{t \cdot P(X_{c+s-k}=t)}{c+s-k}\right)$$

Does anybody know how I get from the left to the right side?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a $t$ multiplying the probability in the RHS?

Comment: I do not get the same as you, I give you an answer by just doing a change of variable in the inner sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do $t=m-k$ so your sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{m=k}^{s+c-1}\frac{c+s-m}{c+s-k} P(X_{c+s-k}=m-k)=\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{t=0}^{s+c-1-k}\frac{c+s-m+k-k}{c+s-k} P(X_{c+s-k}=m-k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{t=0}^{s+c-1-k}\frac{c+s-k-(m-k)}{c+s-k} P(X_{c+s-k}=m-k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=s+1}^{s+c-1} \sum_{t=0}^{s+c-1-k}\left (1-\frac{t}{c+s-k}\right ) P(X_{c+s-k}=t).$$

Comment: You should, then, explain what is the source of your problem in the question because I do not know what I am seeing here.

Comment: I think i am correct the t comes from the variable and the the whole expression has to be multiplied by the probability.

Comment: This is not part of the question. Z is by definition the RHS and expression in 2.18 looks like the LHS, so in the answer we go from Z to 2.18.

Comment: You can delete the -1. Check that when $t=s+c-k$ the summand is $0$.

Comment: Is just definition of Expected value. The expected value is the sum of the probability times the value of the random variable. The random variable is defined as in the inner sum of the RHS.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it in the end:)